# try catch in VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to convert this line from VB to C#:

```
Catch ex As Exception
        DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Đường dẫn không chính xác", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

I used total this line in C#, but I got error at the name "Devcomponent"
Who helps me..

Comment: What is the error?  Are you missing a reference?

Comment: I dont use DotNetBar in C# so I dont add reference in my project. Could I use another code instead  of that line?

Comment: @user3519507 Use MessageBox.Show() instead

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    //do whatever
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

If you don't need `DevComponents` you can use `MessageBox.Show()` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Đường dẫn không chính xác", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
}
```

NOTE:

> but I got error at the name "Devcomponent"

I'm assuming you have imported the .dll for DevComponents and have it in a using statement in your file already, yes?  Also, I don't know anything about that specific method, so I can't advise there...

Comment: catch should be lower case for c# :)

Comment: Nice "catch" (pun intended)